# Convert specific txt to mat file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text

How can I convert a `txt` file (that has `n` rows of data) with the following format:

```
"header1","header2","header3"
1.20,2,3
2.03,3,4
1.05,5,6
8.20,9,4
etc.
```

into a `mat` file that's simply a `2xn` matrix that ignores the first row and first column of the text file and essentially transposes the other columns:

```
2 3 5 9
3 4 6 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, but one function in particular allows starting the read at a given `row` and `column` offset simply in the calling parameter (without having to specify `headerlines` or adding `*` in format specifier): The function [`dlmread`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)

In your case, it's a simple matter of calling it with the right parameters:

```
M = dlmread( 'test.txt' , ',' , 1 , 1 ).' ;

M =
     2     3     5     9
     3     4     6     4
```

The nice thing about this function is it returns a `double` array directly (useful if you only want to read numbers), instead of a cell array like some other functions.

Note that I transposed the result at the end of the line (using the transpose operator `.'`), to get it the way you wanted.

Also note that the last 2 parameters are considered *offset* (as opposed to *start row index*). It means a value of `1` specify an offset of 1, so the reading will start at row index 2 (*first index is 1*).